# Checking if an array is empty with Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, empty-list

I am trying to figure out if an array is empty.  I tried this and it does not work.

```
a = []
if a == []
 alert "empty"
```

I know I can check the length of the array but am curious why this does not work.

Comment: That doesn't work because `a` and `[]` are different objects.

Answer (score 6):

There is no direct empty check for arrays. You could do something like this though:

```
a = []
alert("empty") unless a.length
```